# Cannot get pigpio PWM to work with an AC dimmer module

Tags: gpio, pwm, node.js, pigpio, pi-gpio

I am using an AC dimmer module to dim a 240V light. I would like to use node.js so I am using the pigpio module.

The script is not working as expected as the light bulb goes straight to 100% when I execute the node.js script.

The AC dimmer module is http://www.inmojo.com/store/krida-electronics/item/ac-led-light-dimmer-module-with-heatsink/

Module's Pins:

```
+5V -> device power, DC 5 volts 
SYNC -> zero-cross detector output positive impulse (pulse length 200us) 
GATE -> triac gate input pin 
GND -> ground of low voltage side
```

I have connected Module's VCC, GND and Gate pins to raspberry's +5, GND pin 18 respectively.

[image]
(the wiring is actually done with a Raspberry Pi 3, ignore the Arduino board in the wiring diagram above)

My code:

```
var Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio,
  led = new Gpio(18, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT}),
  dutyCycle = 0;


led.pwmWrite(dutyCycle);

setInterval(function () {
  led.pwmWrite(dutyCycle);

  dutyCycle += 1;
  if (dutyCycle > 255) {
    dutyCycle = 0;
  }
}, 20);
```

I have also tried with the led.hardwarePwmWrite() method, but I am a bit confused as to how this can be used.

Is there anything that can be fixed in my wiring, the above code or by implementing hardwarePwmWrite()?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this works with 3.3V logic?  I don't see any on the page you linked.  I also suspect there is something missing from your code as you seem to be varying a duty cycle but did not set a pulse width (unless there is a default you are relying on).

Comment: What are you doing with the SYNC line?

Comment: @goldilocks I have updated the question adding information about the pins.  The SYNC line is not connected to anything: in the module's producer Arduino example code they are only using the Gate line.

Comment: My point was not "I do not see any reason to believe this works with 3.3V logic on the page you linked".  That doesn't mean it does not, but if you cannot get it to work, just as likely it *doesn't*, and high/low signals from the pi are not being consistently interpreted.  If the load is on whenever the gate is low, and the gate is low all the time because the line logic level voltage is insufficient, that would explain your problem.

Comment: If you have a screen attached to the Pi use [piscope](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) to check for GPIO activity.  GPIO 18 should be toggling regardless of whether 3.3V is seen as high.

Comment: @joan, just checked now with periscope, and yes GPIO 18 is toggling at high rate

Comment: Okay, I suppose that means the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: You're also almost definitely going to need to use the sync line - pwm is basically pointless in this situation because once a triac switches on, it will remain on until the AC zero crossing point. At which point you use the sync to schedule a delay of a percentage of the wave before turning it on again. What you're wanting to be doing is something called trailing edge dimming.